# Determine currently selected Outlook profile

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, profile, office-automation

I'm dealing with several Office installations that have two profiles, primarily in order for the Exchange connection in one profile not to break normal (caldav) based calendars in the other profile.

There are some actions that only should only be applied when a particular profile is active. I detect if Outlook is running (using `psutil`), and if Outlook is not running, things are easy: start outlook with the appropriate profile and then execute the actions.

However if outlook is already running, it could be that the "wrong" profile has been selected on startup. How can I use Python to query the selected profile on a already opened Outlook?

I tried to look in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook` (that is the one under `roaming`) There is a `xyz.xml` for the appropriate profile `xyz`, but it doesn't get touched until Outlook exits. There is a file ending in `.srs` that gets touched immediately when Outlook opens,  but there seems to be no fixed relationship with the name of the profiles (sometimes `xyz.srs` exists sometimes it does not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If outlook.exe is already running, create an instance of the `Outlook.Application` COM object (Outlook is a singleton and you will get a pointer to the already running instance), and read the `Application.Session.CurrentProfileName` property.

Make sure your code is running in the same security context (same local user and matching security settings) - otherwise COM system will refuse to marshal the calls.

---

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
print(outlook.Session.CurrentProfileName)
```